# Problem getting PHP session variable in next pahe if it is assigned by HTML select Tag

Tags: php, session-variables

I need help in transferring the session variable from one page to another while choosing the session variable from the `SELECT` tag. I have given my code below.
I want to show the selected option in the `page1.php` and when the option is selected and after that when user clicks or submit the form then the value of session variable transferred to `page2.php`.
If I don’t redirect my page to `page2.php` then after clicking the submit button I can get the value of the selected session option on the same page. However, for this to achieve I had the click submit. So I found another solution and with jQuery, I got the selected value in `page1.php` one option is selected without submitting the form.
Now when I redirect to `page2.php` then my session variable does not change according to the selected value. Whatever value show it first remain unchanged.

I am new, it may be a silly question, but I am not able to fix it. I appreciate if I can get help/hint
to fix this issue, thank

page1.php:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
}
?>
    <div><?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?></div>
    <form method="post" action="page2.php">          
        <select name="city" id="city>
            <option value="" selected>Please select city</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
            <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>               
        </select>            

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next">
        <br>
        <p id="city"></p>   
    </form>

   *************************
    <script>
        $('select[name="city"]').on('change', function () {
            var option = $('select[name="city"]:checked');
            if (this.value == 'London') {
                $("#city").html("London");
            } else if (this.value == 'Sydney') {
                $("#city").html("Sydney");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

page2.php:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
?>

<div><?php echo $_SESSION['city'];  ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method of using jQuery here, i would suggest the following.
Rather than storing selected drop down value in the `<p id="city"></p>` element.

Define an input tag

`<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value=""/>`

And using the jQuery store the value in this element.

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $_SESSION['city'] = $city;
}
?>
    <div><?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?></div>
    <form method="post" action="page2.php">          
        <select name="city" id="city>
            <option value="" selected>Please select city</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
            <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>               
        </select>            

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value=""/>  
    </form>

   *************************
    <script>
        $('select[name="city"]').on('change', function () {
            var option = $('select[name="city"]:checked');
            if (this.value == 'London') {
                $("#city").val("London");
            } else if (this.value == 'Sydney') {
                $("#city").val("Sydney");
            }
        });
    </script>

 ************************
 ************************
 page2.php

<?PHP
session_start();
?>

<div><?php echo $_SESSION['city'];  ?></div>
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.. really appreciate it.. however, the main issue is still there. because I want to take the session variable to the next page and I got a problem here when I select from the two given options. The first time I got it right but when I go back to page 1 and select another option and redirect to the next page, the session variable which was chosen before remain unchanged.

Comment: @Nadeem Have you tried to unset the session variable in page2?